# I have removed my password now what should I answer when it asks for password?

Tags: password, authentication, users

I used pass word earlier but for now I removed password and used to login without password. Now some actions need administrators aurthentication through password even to set password I it asks for password but actually there is no password and so it doesn't authenticates any actions that need administrators authentication and when I try to use my old password but it also doesn't works. Now what should I do for this case ?

Comment: Please refer this http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password. And to site admins , could be a possible duplicate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/147255/set-for-boot-without-password-still-while-installing-it-asks-for-password-how-t

check out this link will help you..

The password it is asking is your your previous password before changing the settings to NO PASSWORD at booting. If you dont remember open terminal write: passwd
Then system will prompt for new UNIX password set it as desired.

Comment: anytime man. Congrats u resolved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at our guide on how to reset your password using recovery mode, it's fairly simple and should solve your problem :

Have a look at [this page on my website](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/resetpassword.html) for more details.

Comment: Link is not correct.